# Quaternion.LookRotation() not rotating 360 degrees

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion

In my scene I have two cubes one has a tag "Respawn" and another one has the following script attached:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn").transform.position
        );
    }
}
```

When I run it and move around my second cube with "Respawn" tag the first cube doesn't always looks at it, at certain point it just starts rotating the opposite side as if it has bounds to it's rotation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a unity expert, so I'm not posting as a for-sure answer... but does LookRotation need to be relative? like Quaternion.LookRotation( otherObject.transform.position - this.transform.position) ?

Comment: Thanx that helped

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov Also dont use GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag in an update method. You can just find it on Start() or every time it gets removed/instantiated, its not necessary to find it every frame

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Quaternion.LookRotation, use this instead:

```
transform.LookAt(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn").transform.position);
```

This will automatically rotate the object to look at the desired position, which in this case is the position of the Respawn object.

I would also really recommend storing the Respawn object as a variable instead of searching for it every frame.

EDIT:
Ignore the stuff above. If you want to be able to use Quaternion.LookRotation so you can, for example, use Lerp or Slerp, you just have to make the position relative as david van brink pointed out, so it will look like this:

```
Vector3 diff = (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn").transform.position) - transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (diff);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it but the rotation is instant which isn't what I want

Comment: That's why I want to use quaternion.lookrotation() cause I can also use slerp after.